# Json records not showing all data. How to work with the "per_page" attribute?

Tags: json, api, curl

I'm working with the softqare Red Hat Satellite in order to keep my Linux servers updated. In order to doing that I also need to do get all the updates available using curl, like this:

```
curl --request GET --insecure --silent --user username:password https://myMachine/katello/api/errata
```

This is what the command returns

```
{"total":536,"subtotal":536,"page":1,"per_page":20,"error":null,"search":null,"sort":{"by":"updated","order":"desc"},"results":[{errata1},{errata2},...{errata20}}
```

As you can see the total of errata that I have available is 536, however it only returns 20 erratas. This happens because of the per_page attribute.
Is there a way to make the curl show the 536 results or is it possible to do a PUT request in order to changer the per_page data?
What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to change how much data I want to be shown per_page using this command:

```
curl --request GET --insecure --silent --user username:password https://myMachine/katello/api/errata?per_page=100
```

I can also specify the page with the following curl:

```
curl --request GET --insecure --silent --user username:password https://myMachine/katello/api/errata?page=1&per_page=100
```